# Flutter new Image.network foreach in ListView

Tags: flutter

I'm totally new to Flutter and Java based languages in general, coming from PHP background myself. This is going to be a very beginner question:

I'm creating a new Network.image via ListView like this:

```
new Image.network(snapshot.data[index].imageurl.toString() ?? ''),
```

ok, works great as the snapshot.data[index].imageurl is taken as:

```
data ['content'][0]['imageurl']
```

and defined as:

```
String imageurl;
```

However what I'd like to do is to take the whole array:

```
 data ['content']['imageurl']
```

which I suppose should be defined as:

```
List imageurl;
```

and loop through it to create own Image.network for each entry in array.

I have tried multiple things, including:

```
return new Column(
crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
   children: <Widget>[
      snapshot.data[index].imageurl.forEach((data) {
        new Image.network(snapshot.data[index].imageurl.toString() ?? ''),
}
```

But foreEach loop is giving me an error:

"The expression here has a type of 'void', and therefore  cannot be used.

How can I actually achieve this? Out of ideas here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so I finally figured it out.

```
List<Widget> result = content.map((c) => Image.network(snapshot.data[index].imageUrl.toString())).toList();
```

And to get the output the result I did return new Column:

```
children: result,
```

Answer (score 3):

`Iterable.forEach` is for calling a function on every item of an Iterable. It doesn't produce any output (returning `void`), and anything returned from the provided function is discarded.

To produce a new `List` from an existing `List` or `Iterable`, you'll want to use the [`Iterable.map`](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.1.1/dart-core/Iterable/map.html) method.

For example:

```
List<Widget> result = snapshot.data[index].imageurl.map((data) {
  // Make sure to return the result.
  return Image.network(snapshot.data[index].imageurl.toString())
}).toList(); // Call to convert the Iterable into a List.
```

There is another potential issue: `x.toString() ?? ''` is unnecessary because toString() should never return null - even `Null.toString()` returns `"null"`.

Comment: Many thanks for the answer! Understood about the .forEach.  I did try your example, but what I am getting is an error: The element type 'List<Image>' can't be assigned to the list type 'Widget'. when trying to add it inside of the ListView.builder

Comment: It sounds like you are passing the result where a single widget is required. Make sure your code looks like this:

Column(children: snapshot.data /** rest of code **/ .toList()),

Comment: I was yes. That indeed fixed that issue. Now I only have to figure out how to view the return like I was doing above in the example via new Image.network (yes, very new to it all so quite lost with things). But thank you, that fixed that issue. Could you perhaps help me out with that as well please? All I'm getting at the moment is the loader icon when I'm trying to run it.

Comment: Actually forget the latest answer. I was missing List<Widget> result =  from the beginning. Getting "missing selector such as <identifier> or [0]

Answer (score 0):

```
ListView(
    children: snapshot.data.docs.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
          return Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Container(
                  height: 500.h,
                  width: screenSized.width,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  image: DecorationImage(
                  image:NetworkImage(
                   document["userImage"]),
                  fit: BoxFit.cover
                  ),
                ),
             ),
           );
         }).toList(),
        );
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).